# How do we run single program in parallel multiple times using bash script?

Tags: c, bash

I have run the following program test.c using the command

```
$  nohup bash -c 'gcc test.c && ./a.out' > out1.txt & nohup bash -c 'gcc test.c && ./a.out' > out2.txt

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define myrand32 ((unsigned int) (4294967296.0*drand48()))
 

int main()
{
   
    srand48(time(NULL));
 
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        printf(" %u ", myrand32);
 
    return 0;
}
```

But I got the same output in two different output files.
Actually I have one node with 32 CPUs and I want to run the same programme in 32 CPUs parallelly such that it will generate different ooutputs in the output files.
How can I do this using bash scripts? or any other suggestions.

Comment: `time(NULL)` has high chance to be the same value when ran in parallel. You should use another source of random such as `/dev/random`.

Comment: Note that the code you show does not fulfill the needs of a [mcve]. It contains errors which will stop your build.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `nohup` or to invoke `bash`. And you definitely don't need to build the exact same program twice (with the second overwriting the executable of the first).

Comment: Why don't you generate all files from a single C program?

Comment: Maybe explain what you wanted to accieve: You code tried to write the same file `a.out` twice and run it. In Linux this will give a "ext file busy" and the second write is denied while the first programm is still executing. And the question has nothing to do with running a program in parallel, but obviously with the outcome of doing so.

Comment: Btw: If you use bash anyways, you could replace the C program by `od -v -tu4 -An < /dev/urandom | head -n1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like

```
for i in $(seq 32); do (./a.out > out$i &); done
```

This runs 32 copies of your program, all in the background, in parallel, with their outputs redirected to files `out1` through `out32`.

You got the same output in two files because, as @MikeCat noted, two copies of your program ran within the same exact second, so `time(NULL)` returned the same value, so both invocations ran with the same seed.  A simple way to work around that problem is to do something like

```
srand48(time(NULL) ^ getpid());
```

A better fix would be to read a seed from `/dev/random`, but that's mildly trickier.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am getting this. Test.c: In function ‘main’:
Test.c:11:26: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getpid’; did you mean ‘getenv’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     srand48(time(NULL) ^ getpid());
                          ^~~~~~
                          getenv

Comment: @Sanu `man getpid` says you need to `#include <unistd.h>`.